# How to Write Conditional Operator with Multiple Conditions in PHP

Tags: php

I have below Code

```
<?php
echo $show_li = ($show == 1) ? 'Verified' : '' ;
echo $show_li = ($show == 2) ? 'Un-Verified' : '' ;
echo $show_li = ($show == 3) ? 'Matrimonial' : '' ;
echo $show_li = ($show == 4) ? 'Banned' : '' ;
?>
```

I want to wrote it in a Single Line But it's not working

```
echo $show_li = ($show == 1) ? 'Verified' : (($show == 2) ? 'Un-Verified' : (($show == 3) ? 'Matrimonial' : (($show == 4) ? 'Banned' : '');
```

Kindly Clear me where i did mistake.

Comment: It's generally considered a bad practice to use the ternary operator for more than 2 options, because it makes the code difficult to read. Check that parentheses are correctly balanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were missing some parens at the end of your statement. This should work

```
echo $show_li = ($show == 1) ? 'Verified' : (($show == 2) ? 'Un-Verified' : (($show == 3) ? 'Matrimonial' : (($show == 4) ? 'Banned' : '')));
```

However, this code is a bit hard to parse as a developer. I would opt for something that might be easier to read such as this example using switch case.

```
switch ($show) {
    case 1:
        $message = 'Verified';
        break;
    case 2:
        $message = 'Un-Verified';
        break;
    case 3:
        $message = 'Matrimonial';
        break;
    case 4:
        $message = 'Banned';
        break;
    default:
        $message = '';
}

echo $message;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily go without all the parentheses.

```
echo $show_li = $show == 1
    ? 'Verified'
    : $show == 2
        ? 'Un-Verified' 
        : $show == 3
            ? 'Matrimonial'
            : $show == 4
                ? 'Banned'
                : '';
```

But as stated by James so many conditions are hard to read in a ternary statement.